# How to find the second to last element in a vector in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying to build a program that uses the second to last element in a vector, so far I've used:

```
(arr2.rbegin()+1)
```

If I use a comparison operator in a conditional such as:

```
if(arr2.rbegin()+1 == true)
```

I get an error message: `no match for operator ==`

Comment: `arr2.rbegin()+1` is an iterator, not a value. Try using `*`: `if (*(arr2.rbegin()+1) == true)`

Comment: `*(arr2.rbegin()+1)` or `arr2[arr2.size()-2]`

Comment: @JoshG79: In that case, the type you get when dereferencing the iterator needs to define an appropriate operator== as well.

Answer (score 87):

Many of the answers and comments have the right idea but really ugly syntax.  Here are two nice ways to express that.

```
arr2.end()[-2] // end() is past the last element, -1 for last element, -2 for second-last
arr2.rbegin()[1] // rbegin() is reverse order starting at 0 for last element, 1 for second-last
```

Demo: http://ideone.com/2cZeUq

It works because RandomAccessIterator, which `vector` has, is required to provide `operator[]` such that `it[n]` is equivalent to `*(it + n)`, just like for pointers.

So the code in your question becomes just

```
if (arr2.rbegin()[1]) // test penultimate element
```

Comment: @Federico: no, `front()` and `back()` give references, not iterators.  Pointer arithmetic doesn't work on references.  You could do `(&arr2.back())[-1]` but that's uglier than using the iterators.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! :)

Comment: I always forgot that vector have random access iterator...

Answer (score 7):

looking at the documentation here

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/?kw=vector

I'd expect you to access your element by

```
secondToLast = myVector[myVector.size() - 2];
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be minus 1 rather than minus 2, seeing how indices are zero-based?

Comment: @Damon: No, it shouldn't.  The indices run from `0` to `size()-1`, with `size()-1` being the last.  Therefore the next-to-last is `size()-2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try doing like this:-

```
if(*(arr2.rbegin()+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes there might be less than 2 items in the list, so myVector.size() - 2 or other direct accessors will throw an error. I've done the following . . .

```
if (myVector.size() > 1)
{
    secondToLast = myVector[myVector.size() - 2];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by "second to last element".  Take the following iterator definition...

```
vector<int>::iterator it = arr2.end();

it--; 
it--;
```

You have to decriment the iterator twice because when you declare the iterator to "point" to the end, it actually references the location AFTER the last element in the vector.

Dont forget that when you want the value that the iterator points to, you have to dereference it. like so...

```
cout << *it;
```

Answer (score 0):

Mostly for lulz, but if your elements are non-scalar and you need to access a member of the element in question, you can use the `++->` construction:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> arr = ...;

auto grug = arr.rbegin()[1].first;
auto leet = arr.rbegin()++->first;
assert(grug == leet);
```

The way it works is we post-increment the iterator returned by `rbegin()` with `++` and then access it with `->`. It is actually superior to the clearest `[1]` form in the sense it will work on any iterator, not only random access iterator.

Post it on review and get some popcorn.

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways you can access elements from the back
one you can use is the back property that comes with std::vector container
and if you want to access an element from the back (either last element or up to n)
you can do this

std::vector vec{1,2,3};
int lastsecond = vec.back()-1; will give you -> 2;

you can check vector properties which there is a decent bit.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector

Comment: `vec.back()-1` gets the last element and subtracts 1; it does *not* get the second-last element. Your code only seems to produce the correct output because your data coincidentally makes it look that way. It's not correct though.